# Я был увлечен своим занятием

Tags: грамотная-речь

Будет ли верно высказывание: "Я был увлечен своим занятием больше, чем бы то ни было"?

Comment: Интересно, какой смысл вы вкладываете в "своё занятие".

Comment: "Свое занятие" может быть каким угодно) Хоккей, лыжи или проектирование роботов)

Comment: вот смотрите, чтобы понять, что вообще вы хотите сформулировать, нужно понять, какой смысл вы вкладываете в слова и выражения. Вот примеры употребления выражения "своё занятие" https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkcqGAoICAsQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJAoiCiAKA3JlcRIZChfRgdCy0L7RkSDQt9Cw0L3Rj9GC0LjQtTAB почитайте, пожалуйста, мне кажется, что в эти слова вкладывают обычно иной смысл.

Comment: Не совсем вас понимаю, Буратино) Свое занятие это дело, жизнь, что-то, чем занимается или увлечен человек. Давайте скажем работа, этот смысл я и вкладываю в написанное мною выражение

Comment: Поняла вас, кажется, можно уточнить тогда, что в моем контексте занятие это какой-то процесс или период работы, общего дела, которым занимается человек. Например, работа над временным проектом в исследовательском центре

Comment: Тогда это совместное занятие), если общее. Это первый момент. Второй, если вы описываете: Свое занятие это дело, жизнь, что-то, чем занимается или **увлечен** человек. Но тут же пишите "увлечён своим занятием" - то есть уже тавтология "увлечён" уже содержится в "своё занятие", на то оно и своё. Но возможно, вы хотели сказать "погружен или углублён в своё занятие"? Такие эпитеты уместны. И это еще не доходя до части, после запятой, потому что там еще что-то не совсем уместное)

Comment: А вообще "своё занятие" употребляют чаще вместо повторения, того чем занимаешься именно сейчас, либо когда понятно, чем занимается человек: пекарь бросил своё занятие - то есть перестал печь. Ну и также несколько странно будут выглядеть фразы: дровосек любил своё занятие больше, чем рыбалку. Это странно, если бы он любил рыбалку больше, он не бы был дровосеком, а был бы рыбаком) а тут получается какая-то чепуха с повторами очевидности) То есть у вас получилась забавная фраза, но она абсолютно непонятная, но забавная своей непонятностью) Кажется повторы должны быть оправданы, но нет)

Comment: Насчём "чем бы то ни было" - это сложнее, чем сказать что-то конкретное, например, *чем рисованием*. Тогда появляется смысл во фразе. Но если это набор местоимений и частиц, то даже если тот вариант который предлагает Иван, все равно сильно лучше не становится, не ясно о чём идет речь) То есть, например: Я был увлечён своим занятием больше, чем рисованием ранее. - вроде понятно. А больше, **чем чем бы то ни было** - тоже чепуха), хотя вроде не содержит явных речевых ошибок. Но это "чем-чем" выглядит как заикание и не вносит конкретики, при том, что "своё занятие" - тоже референс неконкретный.

Comment: Авторские проекты тоже бывают) В остальном благодарю вас, я подумаю над тем, что вы написали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, здесь пропущено второе слово **"чем"**. Поясняю, почему оно необходимо.
**"Я был увлечен своим занятием больше, чем..."** - здесь мы имеем сравнительный оборот, который нужно чем-то завершить, добавив какое-то сравнение.
Вы выбрали устойчивое словосочетание **"что бы то ни было"** в соответствующей форме. Но применение этого словосочетания никак не отменяет необходимость использовать союз **"чем"**. Поэтому вам придется написать **"чем"** два раза подряд.
Я сейчас не буду рассуждать о том, насколько красиво будет выглядеть такое повторение, но если вы хотите применить именно это сравнение, вам придется написать так:

> **Я был увлечен своим занятием больше, чем чем бы то ни было.**

Comment: чем чем бы то ни было - шедевр, однако)

Comment: Согласен, смотрится так себе. Именно поэтому я и написал, что красоту этого выражения обсуждать не буду: его плюс только в том, что оно уже хотя бы не содержит речевых ошибок.

Comment: Тогда получается "...больше, чем что бы то не было?"..

Comment: @Marusya, если бы сравнительный оборот относился к подлежащему - тогда да. Например: "Это занятие увлекает больше, чем что бы то ни было". Но так как в данном случае сравнительный оборот относится к дополнению "занятием", он должен иметь ту же форму. Попробуйте заменить словосочетание "что бы то ни было" на какое-нибудь простое слово, и вы сразу почувствуете нужную форму. Например: "увлечен пением больше, чем рисованием", но не "увлечен пением больше, чем рисование".

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю над этим